# Webpack is not compiling new files into bundle

Tags: webpack

I'm running webpack-dev-server and it keeps serving old files, any ideas? The new bundle still has the old files.

When I run webpack it compiles the new files into a new bundle

config:

```
module.exports = {
  context: __dirname + "/app",
  entry: "./main.js",
  output: {
    path: __dirname + "/dist",
    filename: "bundle.js"
  },
  devtool: "#source-map",
  module: {
    loaders: [
      // Transpile any JavaScript file:
      {test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'babel-loader'}
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    // you can now require('file') instead of require('file.js')
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.json']
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us your webpack and webpack-dev-server config?

Comment: @emergence have done so)

Comment: Oh I don't have a deb server config. I'll research it

Comment: As far as I know, the server only builds the files on the fly and streams them to the browser (instead of building them like webpack itself does). See this comment from the creator: https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/62#issuecomment-58856998 I'm not sure if this solves your problem though.

Comment: not really, I just want it to work like grunt watch or ember-cli

Comment: So you want to use the server and build the files at the same time? In that case, you either have to run both webpack *and* webpack-dev-server at the same time or run webpack and use another server (such as node express server, python simpleHTTPServer, etc...).

Comment: Thanks that works but I still have to tell browser to refresh the page

Comment: You can use live-server https://www.npmjs.com/package/live-server